# Override default setting for category archive output (in twentytwelve)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this snippet in a custom category template which outputs the last X posts of that category.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );   endwhile; twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Problem is this outputs the posts as excerpts.. How can I change it to `the_content()` without affecting all the other loops? I only need to have the_content here.

Do I need to manually output the title, then the date, then author and then `the_content()` or can I just replace something in the snippet above ?

Comment: you can use the_content() to output the content, the loop above is loading a html template for the post. You can just delete that or create a new template. I assume the code above is in a template?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given, it seems that you have customized the content.php template.

To show the content just for your category page, look, you'll need to add that condition. As you did not add the code for content.php, I can't exactly say where to add it, but you have to do somthing like this

```
if(is_category()) {
  the_content();
}else{
  the_excerpt();
}
```